# Mass action not working in Magento 2

Tags: uicomponent, massaction, magento2.4.1

In my custom module I am showing the records in the admin panel grid using **ui_component** and it's showing good. When I am selecting **count()-1** records the selected parameter is passing to controller to delete the records as shown below pic.

[image]

When I am selecting the all records from **Mass Action** the selected parameter is not passing to controller see below pic.

[image]

for this I have written the **ui_component** xml file as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">abc_company_grid.abc_company_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">abc_company_grid.abc_company_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">abc_company_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="abc_company_grid_data_source" >
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">abc_company_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">abclogger_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">abclogger_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">abc_company_grid.abc_company_grid.abc_company_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">abclogger_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="dynamicsnav/index/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Logger</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="abc_company_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">abclogger_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="abclogger_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="message">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Message</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="type_of_message">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Type of Request</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Created at</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn class="ABCSolutions\Company\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\abcLoggerActions" name="actions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>abclogger_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

[image]

And the Controller method

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if (array_key_exists('selected', $params)) {
            try {
                foreach ($params['selected'] as $key => $id) {                         
                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create(ABCLogger::class);
                    $model->load($id);
                    $model->delete();
                }
                $message=__("Logs deleted successfully.");
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong. Please try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Something went wrong. Please try again.'));
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('dynamicsnav/index/index');
    }
```

Can you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi Updated my thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your ui_listing :

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="module/controller/MassDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
```

In your MassDelete controller class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Controllername;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 */
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::delete');
    }

    /**
     * Execute action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
                
        $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $bar) {
            $bar->delete();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Hope, that works.

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Did you try my controller? and is ABClogger your resource model?

Comment: See problem is not the controller the selected record/ids **$params['selected']** are not coming in parameters  i.e `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`. See my thread. Thank you.

Comment: I think that has to do something with this dependency `use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;` that you're not using in your controller. This controller is working perfectly at my side. I'd suggest you to try it once and see what happens.

Comment: let me try @Abdul